# Order by rand() with same id

Tags: mysql, random

Hi everyone i'm looking for a little help with a query.
I have 2 tables

[image: table]

I need to get all answers from a questions randomly.With the query

```
Select * From questions,answers WHERE questions.id = answers.iddomanda
```

the result is perfect but if i use the order by rand this is the outcome.

[image: table2]

there's a way to get, randomly, the questions end, randomly, the answers?
Something like

```
id iddomanda question         answer 
4  4         Come va ?        bene
4  4         Come va ?        male
1  1         Come ti chiami ? Michele
1  1         Come ti chiami ? Carlo
2  2         Di dove sei?     San Salvo 
2  2         Di dove sei ?    Vasto 
3  3         Dove vai ?       Lontano 
3  3         Dove vai ?       Lontanissimo 
3  3         Dove vai ?       In giro 
3  3         Dove vai ?       Di la
```

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is randomize the question id and then join your answers to it like so.

```
SELECT t.id, t1.iddomanda, t.question, t1.answer 
FROM
(   SELECT id, domanda as question
    FROM questions 
    ORDER BY RAND()
) t
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT iddomanda, risposta as answer
    FROM answers
) t1 on t1.iddomanda = t.id;
```

the nice thing about this query is you are being very minimalistic.. the questions table is going to be much smaller than the answers table so you just need to randomize ONE table and the smaller one at that... and then when you join it will join them to the already randomized table!

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46d99/1)

Comment: Really thanks ! I added a Order BY rand () for the answer, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: this is an another way  SELECT * FROM questions T1
inner join answers T3 on T1.id= T3.iddomanda
inner join (select id, rand() as casuale from questions) T2 on T2.id= T1.id
order by casuale, rand()

Comment: @Usatei yea but that is using the order by RAND() function twice which will be a LOT slower on a large table :) just as a FYI

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to select the questions and answers in random order:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM questions
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 10) AS q
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM answers
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 100) AS a
ON q.id = a.iddomanda
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: this seems like it would cause performance issues because you are putting a RAND() on both tables... RAND() as you probably know (but the OP may not) is fairly slow because it puts a random number for each row before it even starts selecting things!!

Answer (score 0):

Ordering by `rand()` will give a random order.

What you want is an order by *first* Question id and *second* in equal question ids randomly:

`... order by id, RAND() ...`

Comment: If I use the order by id, rand() the questions will be ordered by id, and not randomly